# CSS Overlapping div's

Tags: html, css

i have 4 div's:

```
#centered {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 52%;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    margin-top: -250px; /* Half the height */
    margin-left: -250px; /* Half the width */
    }
#container{
    width:100%;
}
```

(left and right are in this container)

```
 #left{
        float:left;
        width: 260px;
        height: 600px;
    }
    #right{
        float: right;
        top: 50%;
        width: 160px;
        height: 600px;
    }
```

the div centered is always in the center of the page, and the other two are at the sides.
using

```
body { min-width:1150px; }
```

there always is a space between #centered and #right.
but when i shrink the page, no space is being kept between #centered and #left,
causing overlap. How can i do this?

Comment: give your html code too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a guttering `<div>` and adjust your positions accordingly, or you could reduce the width of `#left`. Using percentages rather than px for the width of `#left` and `#right` will make it smoother when resized.